# How to avoid free corruption in libpng when free variable

Tags: c, malloc, free, libpng

I use libpng in C to load png image and retrieve pixel data.

My code rely on that example:

> [http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html](http://zarb.org/%7Egc/html/libpng.html)

I modify the code to retrive pixel data in a array:

```
  int total_size = 0;
  row_pointers   = (png_bytep*) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * image->height);
  int* line_size = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * image->height);
  for (unsigned int y = 0; y < image->height; y++) {
    int pixel_row_nb = png_get_rowbytes(png, info);
    printf("malloc %d \n", pixel_row_nb);
    total_size += pixel_row_nb;
    line_size[y]    = pixel_row_nb;
    row_pointers[y] = (png_bytep) malloc(pixel_row_nb * sizeof(png_byte));
  }
  printf("total %d vs %d \n", total_size, image->height * image->width * 4);

  png_set_bgr(png);

  png_read_image(png, row_pointers);
  png_destroy_read_struct(&png, &info, NULL);
  fclose(fp);

  for (unsigned int y = 0; y < image->height; y++) {
    if (y == 0) {
      strncpy((void*) image->data, (void*) row_pointers[y], line_size[y]);
    } else {
      strncat((void*) image->data, (void*) row_pointers[y], line_size[y]);
    }
  }

  // Now release png data
  for (unsigned int y = 0; y < image->height; y++) { free(row_pointers[y]); } /// CRASH
  free(row_pointers);
```

I get a corruption fault on that line previously mention:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff6eb48b1 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff6efd907 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff702adfa "%s\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff6f0497a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff702cad0 "double free or corruption (out)")
    at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff6f0bee5 in _int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x555557059aa0, av=0x7ffff725fc40 <main_arena>)
    at malloc.c:4278
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x555557059ab0) at malloc.c:3124
#6  0x000055555556665f in utils_image_load (image=0x55555702c190, 
    image_path=0x7fffffffc2d0 "/home/xav/data/image.png") at src/utils.c:216
```

I don't really understand why. I notice first, the line width is not equal. Is it normal?
Yhis is the reason why I add a line_size array. First I thougth it was the reason of the corruption but not.

Edit: Solution

Use memcpy instead strncpy and strncat.

Comment: A different problem: `strncpy` and `strncat` are for null terminated strings. Use `memcpy` to copy binary data.

Comment: Aren't all the rows the same size? Why do you need a `line_size[]` array?

Comment: My guess : stack/heap smashing when filling `image->data`. The `strncpy` and `strncat` are meant to manipulate ASCIIZ pointers and rows data **are not** ASCIIZ. So when rows have no null terminator, the concat operation will fill for `line_size[y]` **at the first null byte of `image->data` found**. Thus, if `image->data` isn't initially zeroed, you have an _undefined behavior_ with the concat operation, leading to smash the stack/heap for row_pointers.

Comment: Indeed I thought it has different line size but they are all the same.

Comment: To be more clear, the first `strncpy` will copy `line_size[y]` bytes in `image->data` if there is no null byte in the row. That leaves `image->data` in an _undefined state_ if it was not initially zeroed. The following `strncat` may then write 'outbound' if the `image->data` is filled with non null bytes. See `strncpy` documentation :  _If count is reached before the entire array src was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated._

Comment: I modify with memcpy and it resolves the memory corruption. Thank you.